# There is space between <input type="text"> and its subsequent element <div>. Is there a way to make them visible inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Kindly suggest the suitable modification to remove the space between the *input type="text"* and the subsequent *div* element. If i set width of *input type="text"* element to 180px and width of the following *div* to 20px; the *div* overflows and moves down. I would not want to use *margin-left: -...px* on the child div to make it appear inline **(because it take -8px in firefox and -6px in chrome to make them appear inline)** but I would still want both the elements to be displayed perfectly inline without any empty spaces between them and edge to edge of its parent element across all browsers.

Kindly suggest...

css:

```css
#parentDiv {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
  border: dotted 2px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#parentDiv input[type="text"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 175px;
  height: 90%;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#parentDiv div {
  background-color: #57c274;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  /*margin-left: -6px;*/
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id=parentDiv>
  <input type="text">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply `float` your elements

Than apply this styles to make it nice across all modern browsers:

```
#parentDiv {
    width: 200px;                                               /* 200- */
    height: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
    border: dotted 2px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#parentDiv input[type="text"] {
    box-sizing:border-box;       /* Respect the designer :) */
    width: 180px;                                               /* 180= */
    height: 100%;                /* Yey! finally 100% */
    border: none;
    float:left;                  /* Go left */
}
#parentDiv div {
    background-color: #57c274;
    float:right;                 /* Go right */
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;                                                /* 20 */
    text-align: center;
}
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/lequqe/5/edit?html,css,output)***

Comment: Yey

This solution solves the issue across both the browsers.
thanks a ton...

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<div id=parentDiv>
  <input type="text">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id='parentDiv'>
  <input type='text' value='' /><div></div>
</div>
```

In HTML either a single or multiple spaces or a line break will create a single white space. Since there is line break before `<div>` there is a text node there.

Comment: Hey there thanks for help.

I must really appreciate how swiftly you caught such minute error. I must admit i am certainly impressed...

Comment: Your suggestion above soles the issue in chrome but still persists in firefox when setting width of input to 80% and div to 20%...

Comment: I usually do `*{display:block, float:left}`.

Answer (score 0):

here's a snippet extending PHPglue's answer

```css
#parentDiv {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
  border: dotted 2px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#parentDiv input[type="text"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 90%;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#parentDiv div {
  background-color: #57c274;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  /*margin-left: -6px;*/
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id=parentDiv>
  <input type="text"><div></div></div>
```